# How to implement persistent bottom sheet like Apple Maps

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was wondering how you would go about implementing a persistent bottom sheet that has an initial height and then expands into two positions.

Initial position - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QlPu.png

Expanded position - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeXTJ.png

Fullscreen position - https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6WBq.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to implement something similar to this, and so far my research led me to using customscrollview and slivers. But the UI is not quite the same, the main ui behind (based on your image = map) would actually animate a bit upward after trying to expand the view on top.

I will be trying out other things, like using stack with the front view having the same implementation as the customscrollview I mentioned, and making it transparent so the back view would still be displayed.

I hope this helped.